Is there a way to print incremental time instead of absolute time with Python logging
When using Python logging, asctime is very handy in looking at the hotspots in code. However, I have to decode or post-process the log to show incremental time taken between each log message.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

Is there a way to print incremental time instead?
I understand logging is meant to handle parallel threads etc., so incremental may not make much sense, but it helps a lot in simple cases.
What I get now
2024-09-13 12:37:19,981 - INFO - Got a Chunk of Data in 1.662097 seconds
2024-09-13 12:37:19,989 - INFO - Processed the Chunk in 0.008471 seconds
2024-09-13 12:37:19,993 - INFO - Optimized the Data in 0.002940 seconds

What I am looking for
1.662097 - INFO - Got a Chunk of Data in 1.662097 seconds
0.008471 - INFO - Processed the Chunk in 0.008471 seconds
0.002940 - INFO - Optimized the Data in 0.002940 seconds

Or something similar

Yes, the order is important, code runs in a single thread. Time take nin example is arbitrary. Can be ignored.

I am not following? You can log the time between the last logging record. That is possible having a custom formatter. Is that what you are looking for?

I think that works, thank your for your answer

You can use log record factories to add custom attributes. This way any module can use the custom logging without having to pass Filter or Adapter objects around, tying yourself to one type of logging (e.g., Stream, HTTP, etc), or forcing a single format string.
import logging
import time

def getLogRecordFactory():
    'Returns a custom log record factory that adds a deltaTime attribute to the log record'
    oldLogRecordFactory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

    def recordFactory(*args, **kwargs):
        # For the first time, create the lastLogTime attribute (makes delta=0)
        if not hasattr(recordFactory, 'lastLogTime'):
            recordFactory.lastLogTime = time.perf_counter()

        # Calculate the time difference between the current log and the previous log
        currentTime = time.perf_counter()
        delta = currentTime - recordFactory.lastLogTime
        recordFactory.lastLogTime = currentTime

        # Create the log record and add the deltaTime attribute
        record = oldLogRecordFactory(*args, **kwargs)
        record.deltaTime = f'{delta:6.4f} sec'

        return record

    return recordFactory

logging.setLogRecordFactory(getLogRecordFactory())

# Usage:
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(deltaTime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.info("hello 1")
time.sleep(1)
logging.info("hello 2")
logging.info("hello 3")

Sample Output
# 0.0000 - INFO - hello 1
# 1.0008 - INFO - hello 2
# 0.0002 - INFO - hello 3


This is clean and compact, I see one issue, taking last_time from the global variable means that, the first log message shows the elapsed time from the start of the program till when it's called. I think a better way is to use function attributes, also avoiding global variable

@Krishna "the first log message shows the elapsed time from the start of the program till when it's called." What's the preferred alternative? Should the first message always be zero? Or a start_timer() function?

If we are using the logger immediately then it's not and issue, but if it's used much later in the program the delta shown is large, 0 is better than a random delta I feel.

This solution might not be perfect if you log several messages comming from different sources. But you can achieve the desired output by using a custom logging formatter that calculates the incremental time between log messages.
The idea is to subclass logging.Formatter and override its format method to compute the elapsed time since the last log message.
import logging
import time

class IncrementalTimeFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None):
        super().__init__(fmt, datefmt)
        self.last_time = time.perf_counter() 

    def format(self, record):
        current_time = time.perf_counter()
        incremental_time = current_time - self.last_time
        self.last_time = current_time

        record.incremental_time = f"{incremental_time:.6f}"
        return super().format(record)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = IncrementalTimeFormatter('%(incremental_time)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Create a console handler with the custom formatter
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

Testing
logger.info("First time")
time.sleep(1.662097)
logger.info("Got a Chunk of Data in 1.662097 seconds")
time.sleep(0.008471)  # Simulate processing time
logger.info("Processed the Chunk in 0.008471 seconds")
time.sleep(0.002940)  # Simulate processing time
logger.info("Optimized the Data in 0.002940 seconds")
>>>
0.000000 - INFO - First time
1.665573 - INFO - Got a Chunk of Data in 1.662097 seconds
0.012226 - INFO - Processed the Chunk in 0.008471 seconds
0.005708 - INFO - Optimized the Data in 0.002940 seconds

Note, the timing is not perfect with very short times

@BoppreH , God idea and thanks for the suggestion. I have just updated.
